# Get apt-get dependencies given rosdep key

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I know using `rosdep install` will install the dependencies for a given package. However I need to get a list of all the system dependencies for a given package. Is there a way to get the corresponding apt-get entries in the rosdep database given the rosdep key?

i.e the `foo` rosdep key has this entry in the database:

```
foo:
  ...
  debian: [package1,package2,...]
  ...
```

Is there a command that will return `package1 packag2 ...` with rosdep?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220109/get-apt-get-dependencies-given-rosdep-key/) by [theNerd247](https://answers.ros.org/users/24325/thenerd247/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This command will return all system dependencies for a given ROS package (I explicitly specified OS name and ROS version):

```
$ rosdep keys image_transport --rosdistro=jade --os=ubuntu:trusty | xargs rosdep resolve
#ROSDEP[rosconsole]
#apt
ros-indigo-rosconsole
#ROSDEP[catkin]
#apt
ros-indigo-catkin
#ROSDEP[roscpp]
#apt
ros-indigo-roscpp
#ROSDEP[message_filters]
#apt
ros-indigo-message-filters
#ROSDEP[pluginlib]
#apt
ros-indigo-pluginlib
#ROSDEP[roslib]
#apt
ros-indigo-roslib
#ROSDEP[sensor_msgs]
#apt
ros-indigo-sensor-msgs
```

You can filter it further to get only dependencies:

```
rosdep keys image_transport --rosdistro=jade --os=ubuntu:trusty| xargs rosdep resolve | grep -v "#"
ros-indigo-rosconsole
ros-indigo-catkin
ros-indigo-roscpp
ros-indigo-message-filters
ros-indigo-pluginlib
ros-indigo-roslib
ros-indigo-sensor-msgs
```

This might not be what you are looking for since it's not recursive and it works only for ROS packages (not rosdep keys).

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [theNerd247](https://answers.ros.org/users/24325/thenerd247/) on 2015-10-29**:
Exactly what I needed. Thanks! Recursion can be done using a simple bash script.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want to go from rosdep keys to system dependencies, `rosdep resolve` is what you're looking for. If you want to go from a package name to system dependencies, you can use `rosdep keys` along with `rosdep resolve` like `rosdep keys [foo_pkg] | xargs rosdep resolve`.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [theNerd247](https://answers.ros.org/users/24325/thenerd247/) on 2015-10-29**:
Thanks for explaining the difference between these commands. The rosdep documentation is rather slim and vague.